# When kills cacheThreadPool inactive threads? Java

Tags: java, threadpool, worker, threadpoolexecutor

the cacheThreadPool automatically deletes threads if they are inactive for 60 seconds, as far as I know. Only what exactly that means inactive is not clear to me.

My implementation looks like this:

```
public class ProcessHandler {

private class Worker implements Runnable {

    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<MyTask> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    void schedule(List<MyTask> task) {
        tasks.addAll(task);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                var task = tasks.take();
                task.run();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                // perhaps, handle somehow
            }
        }
    }
}

private ExecutorService esMultiThread = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public void submitProcess(List<MyTask> task){
    Worker test = new Worker();
    test.schedule(task);
    esMultiThread.execute(test);
}
```

}

I create a Instance of `ProcessHandler` and then I want to submit task over and over again with `submitProcess`. Every new call of `submitProcess` should start a new thread so that everything is processed in parallel, e.g. if I call submitProcess 10 times fast in a row. These tasks should then be processed by a new Thread from the `cachedThreadPool`.

My question now, while the worker is sleeping, i.e. waiting by `take()`, will the thread be killed if the worker gets nothing for more than 60 seconds, or does the thread live infinitely because "sleeping" is a state which is not considered inactive by the `cacheThreadPool`?

Comment: Why are you using a thread pool to begin with? Everything happens in a single thread here.

Comment: @daniu when i call submitProcess often times, then every call should create a thread with the given tasks and the thread should process these tasks.

Comment: Oh, I misread the code. Yeah this thread will live forever. But why are you taking from the queue, rather than just iterating over it? You do execute all the tasks in that workers thread consecutively, and you can't add any tasks later.

Comment: okay thanks for the answer. Yes, I know that this example is not 100% clear. I'm working on something so that I can create threads when new work needs to be done, and in some cases I need to add some tasks to "old" running threads (adding tasks to the queue of workers). And I was hoping that the thread will be removed/kill if it doesn't get new tasks in its queue within 60 seconds.

Comment: Use `poll() ` with a timeout instead of `take () `.